# Computing $E_x[\mathrm e^{-\theta^2(\tau-\sigma)/2}]$ when $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are first exit times of an interval.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I wanted to follow the answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574031/application-of-optional-sampling-theorem), there are two steps in particular that I wanted to follow. Here let $B_{t}$ be a Brownian motion starting from a point $x$ contained in an interval $[a,b]$.

Let $\tau := \inf\{B_{t} \notin [a,b]\}$ which we write as an independent sum $\sigma$ and $\tau-\sigma$ where  $\sigma := \inf\{B_{t} \notin [x-z,x+z]\}$
and let $$
u(x)=E_x[\mathrm e^{-\theta^2\tau/2}].
$$
where the subscript $x$ denotes the starting point of the Brownian motion.

Since $\sigma$ and $\tau-\sigma$ are independent, we can write

$$u(x)= E_x[\mathrm e^{-\theta^{2}\sigma/2}])E_{x}[\mathrm e^{-\theta^2(\tau-\sigma)/2}]$$
but then using the using the Markov property at time $\sigma$ it is essentially claimed that

> $$
> E_x[\mathrm e^{-\theta^2(\tau-\sigma)/2}]=\,\tfrac12(u(x+z)+u(x-z)).
> $$

I wanted to understand why, the strong Markov property in my book is written as $E_{x}[Y_{\sigma} \circ \theta_{\sigma}|\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}]=E_{B_{\sigma}}[Y_{\sigma}]$